# Jquery draggable works fine only when its is smaller then container size, not working for images that are greater then container size

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-draggable

what happens is that if i place an image that is smaller then`{1100px,500px}` then drag works fine, but if image is greater then following dimension then horizontal drag is fine but vertical drag is totally messed up.

```
<div class="panzoom" style="width: 1100px; height: 500px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: scroll; position: relative;">

<img title="" id="main_image" src="<?php echo "patternimages/" . $row['img_name'] ?>"> 
</div>
```

Following is my Jquery

```
 $(function() {
    $("#main_image").draggable({containment: ".panzoom", scroll: false});
    });
```

**Fiddle**:http://jsfiddle.net/0au4mz8f/

Comment: The container has an `overflow:scroll`, it is overflowing, we bind the draggable to it and tell it not to scroll while dragging. I'm struggling to see what the "correct" behaviour should be

Comment: @blgt:i tried removing it earliar and has no effect i am going to share a fiddle so you can see for your self.